# React Native Firebase chaining promises

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I am setting a listener on a Firebase node using `.on('value')` and then trying to chain multiple promises once the DB has a value added using `.then()` twice.

However I a getting the error `firebase.database().ref().on(...., *) 'callback' must be a function`

An idea how I can resolve this?

```
database()
  .ref('profiles/users/' + user.uid)
  .on('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Whatever');
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'on' listener uses a callback function whenever the data that the listener is set on changes, that is where your error lies as you did not provide a callback. You can easily accomplish any data manipulation inside that callback without needing to chain a bunch of '.then's. Here is an example of setting the state once the data changes.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

function User({ userId }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = database();
    subscriber.ref(`/users/${userId}`).on('value', snapshot => {
      setUser(snapshot.val());
      //or call another function that will do the rest of the async tasks/data manipulation
    });

    // Stop listening for updates when no longer required
    return () => subscriber();
  }, [userId]);

  // return whatever here
}
```

More use cases here: https://rnfirebase.io/database/usage